# Replacing question mark with single quote: syntax error in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a query to transform all question marks in a column into a single quote character. I am sure I don't have questions marks into my column and an enconding issue caused all single quotes to be transformed into question marks (I had latin1_swedish_ci, now I had utf8-bin).

I wrote these two:

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET description = REPLACE(description, "?","''")
UPDATE `mytable` SET description = REPLACE(description, "??","''")
UPDATE `mytable` SET description = REPLACE(description, "\?","''")
```

All are wrong. What's the correct one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using double quotes for the string delimiter, then you don't need to double up on the single quote.  Try this:

```
UPDATE `museum_workofart`
    SET description = REPLACE(description, "?", "'")
```

A comma after `description` is also needed.

Comment: Thanks, the missing comma was a copy and paste error. The issue is the other one you remarked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another way using escape character:

```
UPDATE `museum_workofart` 
SET description = REPLACE(description, '\?','\'')
```

[**Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5979fe/3) example.